# How to use python subprocess to control command line program correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, os.system

I have an external command line program I'd like to control via python. When using subprocess.open it continuously prints the first command in the terminal. I want to input a series of commands one after another and then terminate the program once it has finished running. I've tried several different method, but nothing seems to work. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong, or help me fix my code? This is what I have:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
program_location = /Fortran/Program/Here/Program

file_location = /Place/For/Input/File/File.EXP
command_list = [file_location, 'expedt', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'powpref', 'genles']
p = Popen(program_location, stdin=PIPE)

for i in command_list:
    ps.stdin.write(i)
```

Comment: Depending on the shell you are executing, you might need to terminate each command with a newline, e.g. `i + '\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to send the lines of input to the process and wait for it to be done.

Comment: Originally I tried communicate, and it kept printing out a line in the terminal over and over again. p.communicate(os.linesep.join(command_list)) didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want all commands to run in parallel, you can run subprocess.call with the help of multiprocessing.

```
import subprocess
import multiprocessing

cmd_1 = ["timeout", "15", "ping", "google.com"]
cmd_2 = ["timeout", "15", "ping", "stackoverflow.com"]

cmds = [cmd_1, cmd_2]

for i in range(len(cmds)):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=subprocess.call, args=(cmds[i],))
    p.start()
```